# Can we use Windows Containers for production

Tags: windows, docker, windows-container

What do you think of Windows Containers in general, because with my team, we are going to use it for a future project? Until now, only Linux containers have been played in combination with ASP.NET Core. Now we want to flush ASP.NET Core onto Windows Containers.
Thanks!

Comment: Windows containers take more size than Linux. We want to shift from Windows to Linux. Yes, Windows containers are ready for production and used in production.

Comment: I use it in production for more then a year. It's fully supported and works as you expect it. We are running old ASP (not ASP.NET) code in them just to show how backward compatible technology is

Comment: As of now, we have no problem with windows containers other than using `System.Drawing` library.